# How can Woocommerce display the products available for purchase first on the main page? (after them "not available")

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to add in functions.php this code

```
class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status {
public function __construct() {
    if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
        add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000);
    }
}
public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;   
    if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
        $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
        $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
    }
}
new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
```

And it works, but only for product category pages (each individual category has its own page with goods), and there is a filtering option for users on these pages. And on the main page, all categories are displayed through the widget "OS Filter products by category" and there is no filtering on the site page itself, which users see.

I would like the code works for the main page too. A template is Orchid Store. Is there a plugin or code for it? I would not like to add a visual filter, according to which users can choose options themselves, but so that the products available for purchase are first visible by default, and then "not available".

Here is how the site looks on the main page:
"Category name"
"not available product", "available for purchase"

"Name of the second category"
"not available product", "available for purchase".

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce allows you to sort products by various criteria, such as price, date added or availability. To display products available for purchase first on the home page, you can follow these steps:

Log in to the WordPress administration panel.
Go to the "Products" section and click "All Products".
Find the "Sort by" option and select "Availability".
Click "Apply" or "Filter" to apply the sorting.
Now the products available for purchase will be shown first in the list and the products not available will be shown later.

If you want this order to be the default on your homepage, you can change your WooCommerce homepage settings. To do this, follow these steps:

Go to the "WooCommerce" section in your WordPress admin panel and click "Settings".
Go to the "Products" tab and find the "Default sort order" option.
Select "Accessibility" as the first option.
Click "Save Changes".

After following these steps, the products available for purchase will be displayed first on the homepage, and the products not available will be displayed later.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have an option for choosing "Settings" -> "Products" 
 -> "Default sort order" -> Select "Accessibility". Maybe it depends on the theme "Orchid Store". I tried plugins, another code. And in my opinion, it should be another way to display categories with goods. On 
page with category I have a filter and it works. Another way is changing plugin to add categories with goods on the main page or use a different code.